# How to find a system of equations such that it has a given solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help with this problem.

> Find a system of eqautions such that its solutions set is:
>   $$SS=\{\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     2 \\
>     3 \\
>     4
> \end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
>     2 \\
>     -3 \\
>     0\\
>     1
> \end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     -2 \\
>     1\\
>     0
> \end{bmatrix}| \ t,s\in\mathbb{R}
> \}$$

What I tried was to write the set as vectors, so I ended up with:
$$x_1=1+2t+s$$ $$x_2=2-3t-2s$$ $$x_3=3+s$$ $$x_4=4+t$$ after that, I don't have too much of a clue on what do do next. What should I do? Hope you can help me.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Just eliminate the variables $s$ and $t$, and you'll have 2 equations in $x_i$.

Comment: And then I just rewrite those equations as a matrix, right?

Comment: A "system of equations" generally means it's expanded, not a single matrix. But they're equivalent.

Comment: Ok, so the system of equations would only have those two equations that I find, right?

Answer (score 0):

Start by analyzing the solution set: the vector $(1,2,3,4)^T$ is a *particular solution* of the system of equations, and the other two vectors span the solution set of the related homogeneous system, that is, they span the null space of the system’s coefficient matrix. Recall that the row space and null space of a matrix are orthogonal complements: you can therefore find a suitable coefficient matrix $A$ for the system of equations by computing the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&0&1\\1&-2&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Finally, you need to find a vector $\mathbf b$ to create the inhomogeneous equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$. You have a particular solution—a vector $\mathbf x$ that solves this equation—so simply compute $A\mathbf x$ to find the corresponding $\mathbf b$.

Comment: For the null space I ended up with ${(-2,-1,1,0), (3,2,0,1)}$. What should I do with that?

Comment: @davidllerenav You now have two vectors that span the row space of the coefficient matrix. Build a matrix with that row space.

Comment: So the basis of the null space span the row space of the coefficient matrix? How do I find such a matrix?

Comment: @davidllerenav When in doubt, return to the definitions: what is the row space of a matrix?

Comment: Is the span of its row vectors.

Comment: @davidllerenav And you have two vectors that span this space, so...?

Comment: So those two vectors are the basis of this space...?

Comment: @davidllerenav More to the point, what does that say about the rows of the coefficient matrix with respect to these two vectors?

Comment: They are linear combinations of these two vectors.

Comment: @davidllerenav Yes, so write down a matrix that has rows that are linear combinations of these two vectors. There’s an obvious one that has only two rows.